# TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null ---node to insertData with mongoDb

Tags: node.js

[image]

this is my problem. now the code is below

```js
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/lcl';

var insertData = function(db,callback){
 var collection = db.collection('user');
 var data = [{"name":"lcl","age":"23","sex":"男"},{"name":"王小猫","age":"22","sex":"女"}];
 collection.insert(data,function(err,result){
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return;
  };
  callback(result);
 })
}
mongoClient.connect(db,function(err,db){
 console.log("连接成功");
 insertData(db,function(result){
  console.log(result);
  db.close();
 })
})
```

above is the code I have written.
Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Check your Db and collections name.

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db_config = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conapp';

var insertData = function(db_config,callback){
var collection = db_config.collection('users');
var data = [{'username':'ddaaaa'}];
collection.insert(data,function(err,result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    };
    callback(result);
})
}
 mongoClient.connect(db_config,function(err,db_config){

 insertData(db_config,function(result){
    console.log(result);
    db_config.close();
 })

})
```

Comment: thanks ,I don't know before lunch code,should I open mongodb?

Comment: yes, I think you are mentioning about opening mongodb shell, If so you have to run mongoDb before the start localhost

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation:

> callback (function) – this will be called after executing this method. The first parameter will contain the Error object if an error occured, or null otherwise. While the second parameter will contain the initialized db object or null if an error occured.

Logically you have to **check for an error** existence **first** and only then perform some operations on `db`

Comment: thanks ,I don't know before lunch code,should I open mongodb?